# Nuxt.js & Firebase.services.analytics causes <v-img /> to be blank with no error

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js, firebase-analytics

I cannot seem to get Firebase/Analytics to work with Nuxt.js. I don't get any errors, but when I use the  I don't get any images loading.

I could use,  and it loads fine. Seems to be a conflict with Nuxt/Vuetify/FirebaseAnalytics

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
firebase: {
  services: {
    analytics: true
  }
}
```

This creates the images to render blank. If I turn it to false, then items load as expected.

These are my dependencies

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "^3.1.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.1.1",
    "@capacitor/network": "^1.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.9.1",
    "@nuxtjs/firebase": "^7.6.1",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "@nuxtjs/universal-storage": "^0.5.9",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "firebase": "8.6.5",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.3",
    "vue-lodash": "^2.1.2"
  },
```

Has anyone encounter this issue? Perhaps someone could expand if they know more? Would like to use Firebase Analytics in my setup.

Comment: What is the content of the image when you inspect the DOM?

Comment: It was empty. There was no broken image, or anything.

Comment: The `src` was empty or the tag wasn't loaded at all?

Comment: The tag wasn't loaded at all

Comment: @kissu, any thoughts on this?